# What is the word after a struct?

Tags: c, struct, declaration, definition

```
struct Books
{
   char  title[50];
   char  author[50];
   char  subject[100];
   int   book_id;
} book;
```

What exactly is "book" at the end?

Comment: Its a variable of type `struct Book`.

Comment: The good thing about that is that you can use unnamed structs like so: `struct { int x; int y;} point;`

Comment: @haccks of type `Book`? do you mean of type `Books`?

Comment: @User; No. I mean of type `struct Book`. `Book` itself is not a type. Its a tag of the given `struct`.

Comment: @haccks why did you remove the `s` though?

Comment: @User; Sorry. That was a typo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a declaration of an instance of a structure of type `struct Books` with name `book`.

It is equivalent to

```
struct Books
{
   char  title[50];
   char  author[50];
   char  subject[100];
   int   book_id;
};

struct Books book;
```

Take into account that in general declarations look like (simplified form)

```
type-sepcifier identifier;
```

where identifier is some declarator. For example

```
int x;
```

And a structure definition also belongs to type specifiers.

So you may write for example

```
struct A { int x; } s;
```

Comment: @haccks. Yes, object. Just like any other memory-occupying entity in C.

Comment: @haccks  Yes, you define objects in C, in C++ and other langauges.

Comment: From the spec: "object: region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent values"

Comment: @CarlNorum; Ahh! Right.

Answer (score 2):

It's a variable name, it's a more compact version of:

```
struct Books
{
   char  title[50];
   char  author[50];
   char  subject[100];
   int   book_id;
};

struct Books book;
```